# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails - One-To-Many relationship - Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am working with one-to-many relation using hibernate.

**profesor.java**

```
   @Entity
    public class Profesor {

         @Id
         @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
         private Long id;

        @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "profesors", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST })
        private List<Classes> classes;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy="profesor", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST })

        @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
        private List<Post> post;

    }
```

My professor table is already in relation with classes table as many-to-many. Now I am trying to connect it with post table as one-to-many.

My post model looks like this:

**post.java**

```
@Entity
public class Post {

  @Id 
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
  private long id;


   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn (name="profesor_id",referencedColumnName="id",nullable=false,unique=true)
   private Profesor profesor;
}
```

Here is how my table post looks in database.

[image: Post table in database]

I am getting following error:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`database`.`#sql-45e3_695`, CONSTRAINT `FKfkqyncksuk5vuw09wam4sryyd` FOREIGN KEY (`profesor_id`) REFERENCES `profesor` (`id`))
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

**SOLUTION:**

First I created post table without profesor_id. I added profesor_id when I started to create relationship between tables and then profesor_id was set to null. When I cleared my table I could run my application normally.

Answer (score 1):

its clear you are violating some constraint, i would say you are trying to remove a proffesor which is already linked to post, try to remove nullable = false

```
 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn (name="profesor_id",referencedColumnName="id",unique=true)
 private Profesor profesor;
```

Comment: Can you put it in code I don't understand like this. Thanks @Amer

Comment: aha okay I understand what are you saying now. Yes I already have it. Check my update. @Amer

Comment: thanks to your last update I came to idea and checked my table and what data I have in it. Problem was that I had posts inserted from before with profesor_id = 0. When I cleared my table I could run my application normally. Thanks! @Amer